# Use a regex to check if an input string is valid from an array of allowed values

Tags: c#, regex

I want to create a validation filter for an Asp .netcore MVC action where if the input of a string is not in a valid collection then it's returns false.

For example.

`IActionResult GetCars(string models)`

valid models only are {"bmw", "mercedes", "volvo"} // case insensitive
So if a user passed in "ford", it'd fail validation.

I'd like to use a validation attribute and so far the only matching one seems to be the Regex attribute.

Is there a straightfoward way to dynamically include a list in the regex for doing this validation?

Something like

`[RegEx(//Source array of valid input strings)]`

`public string Model {get;set;}`

Or are there any other such attributes or methods of doing this without a custom attribute?

On another note is there an open source validation library like this? Seems like a common issue.

Comment: If you have a set of string values and they are not likely to change then it's better create enum for those values and use it as type instead of string.

Comment: We don't have that option, the list can grow quite a bit

Comment: If you have dynamic list regex won't work. If you are getting input from user for this property then you can choose to use drop-down list so that user will select from a set of values. Or you can write your own validator

Comment: To provide some additional context: we are retro fitting a public API so we can't change the input parameter from string. We just want to apply a validation attribute on the model property - I realize it has to be a const value (or in place init array), but looking for other options.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easier to just use an enum, list of the words accepted, and match with those words. I think you are overcomplicating it